# python gtk loop ascii spinner

Tags: python, lambda, pygtk

I am trying (for testing) to have a little ascii spinner object being printed on the screen during a gtk.main() loop.  Currently, I have this code which prints a dot every two seconds.

```
    gobject.timeout_add(2 * 1000,
            lambda : (sys.stdout.write('.'), sys.stdout.flush()) )
    gtk.main()
```

However, I would like the traditional ascii spinner instead but cannot get a good lambda for it.   Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Two good answers but is there a way to do this with a lambda?  Just 'cause lambda are cool.  Nothing more.

Comment: Restricting yourself to only the most awesome language features is like refusing to eat anything but ice cream.

Comment: @ptomato: That is a very good analogy.  To be honest, the restriction is not iron cast at all.  I was just curious how you would do it with lambda or whether it is at all possible.  Curiosity is what kills the cat.  ^_~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you limiting yourself to a `lambda`? To do a spinner, it's easiest to maintain state:

```
class Spinner(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._chars = r"-\|/-\|/"
    self._pos = 0

  def spin(self):
    sys.stdout.write(self._chars[self._pos])
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    self._pos += 1
    if self._pos >= len(self._chars):
      self._pos = 0
    return True

spinner = Spinner()
gobject.timeout_add(2 * 1000, spinner.spin)
```

Note: the above is untested, but should make the general idea clear enough.

Comment: One need to add a `return true` to the `spin()` method if it is going to be used from within the gtk loop -- otherwise, the loop assumes this will be called only once.

Comment: Multiple nits to pick: why double the chars?  And why the "if >= len"?  Use the mod, Luke!  _pos % len() does what you need.  :D

Answer (score 2):

This is something I've just tried in the console without gtk:

```
import sys
from itertools import cycle
from time import sleep

spinner = r'-\|/'

sys.stdout.write('Please wait... ')

for character in cycle(spinner):
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write('\b')
    sleep(1)
```

The two things I like that are slightly different from the previous solution are:

- Use `\b` instead of `\r` to preserve any message you have in the same line (like "please wait")
- `cicle` takes care of what's the next character for you, so you don't need to bother to manage the state yourself.