# How can I modify the STDOUT?

Tags: python, c, bash, terminal, stdout

I'm currently writing a very simple terminal tool and I want to implement the following behavior.

The terminal should display:

```
Downloading "Something" ...
```

And after I have completed the download, I want to replace that line with:

```
Downloading "Something" [Done]
```

I have seen this done o create the following animation:

```
[-]
[\]
[|]
[/]
```

As I don't have much experience with terminal tools, I don't know how to implement this simple behavior. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `clear;echo "|"; sleep 1; clear;echo "/";sleep 1;clear;echo "-";sleep 1;clear;echo "\\";sleep 1;clear;clear;echo "|"; sleep 1; clear;echo "/";sleep 1;clear;echo "-";sleep 1;clear;echo "\\";sleep 1;clear;clear;echo "|"; sleep 1; clear;echo "/";sleep 1;clear;echo "-";sleep 1;clear;echo "\\";sleep 1;clear;clear;echo "|"; sleep 1; clear;echo "/";sleep 1;clear;echo "-";sleep 1;clear;echo "\\";sleep 1;clear;clear;echo "|"; sleep 1; clear;echo "/";sleep 1;clear;echo "-";sleep 1;clear;echo "\\";sleep 1;clear`

Comment: Just for fun … not to be taken seriously. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the backspace character -- `\b`.

Don't forget to flush the output stream, it's likely buffered.

Answer (score 3):

Terminate the intermediate version of the line with "\r".  Any subsequent write will overwrite that line (so long as the new write is at least as long as the original).

There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200973/adding-a-status-bar-to-c-console-applications/) not too long ago; see [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200973/adding-a-status-bar-to-c-console-applications/8201040#8201040) for example code in C++.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an ANSI terminal, you can use the [ANSI Escape Sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) to move the cursor back a line or any other position for that matter. You can then edit starting from the position you bring the cursor to.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void test() {
    const char *msg = "Downloading %s%s";
    printf(msg, "file", "...\r");
    printf(msg, "file", "[Done]\n");
}
```

The magic trick is achieved using "\r" (CR) :P.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that it's not difficult to use `'\b'` to erase the previous value in python (look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8432790/183066)). I recommend you to use [python-progressbar](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/):

```
from progressbar import ProgressBar, RotatingMarker
import time

widgets = ['Downloading something... [', RotatingMarker(), ']']

maxval = 10
progressbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=maxval).start()
for i in range(maxval):
    progressbar.update(i)
    # Do something                               
    time.sleep(0.2)
widgets[-2] = 'Done'
progressbar.finish()
```

The reason is not only that it's possible to do what you're looking for easily, but also that you can add other widgets (ETA, FileTransferSpeed, Percentage, ...) if you wish later to make the progress bar look better depending on your needs.